# Page is not logged in after loading saved cookies

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, cookies, automation

What I want to do is be able to log in once and use the cookies from that to log in several times until the cookies expire. In my test code I've been using gmail but I plan on transferring the code to other sites.

In python, I've been able to save cookies in one script then in a separate script, load those saved cookies to my Chrome webdriver.

However, when I try to refresh the driver I only get the login screen again.

I've mostly followed this simple example:
https://blog.softhints.com/python-pickle-example-cookies/

Although, I had to change the cookies around a bit to get rid of the error: "Message: invalid argument: invalid 'expiry'"

The first script logs into gmail then captures and saves cookies with:

```py
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
pickle.dump(cookies, open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

The next script formats the cookies for selenium and loads them into the driver:

```py
driver = driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox")

cookies = []
for item in pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb")):
    cookies.append({'name': item['name'], 'value': item['value']})
    driver.add_cookie({'name': item['name'], 'value': item['value']})

driver.refresh()
```

I was able to print the cookies along each step of the way to show that they're saving and being loaded however after driver.refresh() I still get the same empty login page when I expect to be brought to the inbox.

Comment: "log in several times until the cookies expire" what do you mean by this?  Seems like you are creating a new browser/session here, so you'd need a new session cookie.

Comment: Ok, I must be thinking about this the wrong way.

I thought that I could simply login, save cookies, then use them in whatever browser/serssion I wanted so I didn't have to log in again.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'll have to try a solution where I have the browser/session stay open between runs.